# jQuery ajax event success handling

Tags: events, jquery, delegates, event-handling

I have the following code multiple times:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "url here",
        success: function (data) {
            // do something here...
        }
    });
```

I'd like to turn this into a function as use it only once, somthing like:

```
function ajax (type, url, complete){
        $.ajax({
           type: type,
           cache: false,
           url: url,
           success: function (data) {
               GO TO THE METHOD SPECIFIED IN complete
        }
 });
```

How would I run a method specified in the complete variable? Is it possible? I've looked at the ajax success event for jQuery but since it would be triggered on every item that uses it, I would then have to check if it is the correct ajax request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `complete` is a reference to a function,

```
function ajax (type, url, complete){
        $.ajax({
           type: type,
           cache: false,
           url: url,
           success: complete
 });
```

Just make sure `complete`'s arguments match what is given by `success`.

EDIT: If `complete` is an object, just find the function on it and use that:

```
success: complete.foo
```

Hope this is what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

If understand question correctly

```
function ajax (type, data, url, complete){
    $.ajax({
       type: type,
       data:data,
       cache: false,
       url: url,
       success: complete
    });
}
var obj={ id:1}
/* example case use */
ajax ('POST', obj 'site.com', myAjaxComplete);

/* a success callback from ajax*/ 
function myAjaxComplete(data){
    // data argument is return data from server

}
```

EDIT: you'll definitely want to add an argument for data to send to server